# Printing spring message in alert using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am integrating js code with spring;
in the return statement they have given the spring message.
I don't know what it means.
How to print the result in alert and see `<spring:message code='BH-MS-0070'/>`.
What are they  using?
I'm providing my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhm, did you try `alert( validateStartDate() );`

Comment: @adeneo: thanks for your reply how to print this spring and see <spring:message code='BH-MS-0070'/>